# Русифицировать TeXstudio

Tags: linux, latex, русификация, tex, texstudio

Установил себе на `Kali Linux` `TeXstudio`, однако она не поддерживает русский язык. Попробовал подключить русско-английский словарь - не помогло. Как русифицировать эту программу?

Набираю такой код:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
    привет
\end{document}
```

Получаю такие ошибки:

```
Package babel Error: Unknown option `russian'. Either you misspelled itd. \ProcessOptions*
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character п (U+043F)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. п
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character р (U+0440)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. пр
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character и (U+0438)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. при
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character в (U+0432)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. прив
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character е (U+0435)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. приве
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character т (U+0442)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. привет
```

Пробовал подключать русский язык и так:

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

Те же ошибки.

Comment: Что значит "не поддерживает русский язык"? В чем это выражается? TeXStudio вполне нормально локализован. Умеет работать с достаточно большим набором кодировок для документов. Вы не можете создать документ на русском языке? - так это проблема Вашего документа (не используете нужные пакеты) или дистрибутива TeX (вернее, установленных пакетов из TeXLive).

Comment: @Vladimir дополнил вопрос.

Comment: TeXStudio здесь совсем не при чём. Вам нужно установить пакеты (пакеты linux) с поддержкой кириллицы для TeXLive. А вообще, рекомендую установить вообще все (ну может кроме явно ненужных языков, типа корейского, китайского и других. если они идут именно отдельными пакетами) возможные пакеты от TeXLive, какие есть в Вашем дистрибутиве + все зависимости, которые он хочет (туда должны войти еще ghostscript, xpdf и подобные программы).

Comment: Для простоты, я бы предложил установить сначала менеджер пакетов  `synaptic`, а в нем можно просто поиском найти все пакеты, относящиеся к TeXLive. Либо можете попробовать выполнить команды `sudo apt-get update` и `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.

Comment: @Vladimir большое спасибо. Очень помогли.

Comment: @Vladimir, пакет называется `texlive-lang-cyrillic`

Answer (score -2):

Зайдите в настройки TexStudio и выберите пакет компиляции PdfLatex: вкладка сборка -> компилятор по умолчанию -> pdfLatex, должно заработать

попробуйте поискать что-то вроде вкладки "настройки" в верхней панеле меню, обычно возле раздела "Помощь" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
у меня английская версия, выглядит как на картинке , здесь нужно найти первую вкладу с настройками студии, далее вкладку "Сборка" и попробовать переключить компиляторы и собрать файл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]